# Print inside widget

Tags: qt, python-3.4, qt-designer

Windows 7, In Python 3.4 I created a very simple program that just prints  "Something". And made a very simple gui in QT Designer for it with 1 button "Print it". Converted .ui file to .py file, made some adjustments.

Everything works, BUT for printing it opens console and prints "Something" there. 
I want this "Something" to be printed INSIDE my widget. And If any mistakes in program - I want them also to be printed INSIDE my widget.

What element of QT Designer should I use? An element which takes all printing from program and prints it inside itself. Or maybe I should use something else but function "Print()"?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably want either a QLabel (setText method) or if there is a bunch of text to print a QTextEdit (append method).

Comment: Thank you!!! You are genius.) Very short and correct answer. How can I mark it as as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably want either a QLabel (setText method) or if there is a bunch of text to print a QTextEdit (append method).

```
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

widget = QtGui.QLabel("My Label")
widget.setText("New Value")
widget.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```